# Nested click handlers in JavaScript a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I was working on this simple plugin for practice purposes and I came across the following issue:
Basically, I want to have multiple image sliders that are being run by the same JS code but obviously independent of each other. The way I currently managed to accomplish this is by having Click handlers for the "Left" and "Right" buttons inside the Click handler of the button that 'activates' that particular slider. Because for some reason, if I have "Left/Right" buttons' handlers outside the 'activate' button handler, they don't get executed.

WORKS:

```
    $('item').click(function() {
       var itemNum = $(this).index() + 1; 
       var $leftArrow = $('#item' + itemNum + ' .left-arrow');
       var $rightArrow = $('#item' + itemNum + ' .right-arrow');

       $leftArrow.click(...);
       $rightArrow.click(...);
    });
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
    var $leftArrow, $rightArrow;

    $('item').click(function() {
       var itemNum = $(this).index() + 1; 
       $leftArrow = $('#item' + itemNum + ' .left-arrow');
       $rightArrow = $('#item' + itemNum + ' .right-arrow');
    });

    $leftArrow.click(...);
    $rightArrow.click(...);
```

So my question is; is it bad practice to do things this way? Like would it start taking up extra memory if the user activates 'item1' slider, then activates 'item2' slider and so on. If so, what better way is there to accomplish this.

Sorry for such a long question, I really appreciate you taking out time to read through it all. :)

NOTE: This is assuming only one slider should be activated at a time.

Comment: Nested click handlers are usually a bad thing because every time the top level click happens, it adds yet another click handler for the other objects and you get duplicate click handlers which is never a good thing.  There are exceptions obviously if you're creating new content each click and then attaching new click handlers to the new content.

Comment: The second one isn't working because your `$leftArrow` and `$rightArrow` don't yet have a value when you try to assign their click handlers

Comment: My goal here to update the `$leftArrow` and `$rightArrow` variables so there click handlers run ONLY in their specific item (so I don't want all the sliders to start moving if one of their arrows is clicked on). How else would you recommend I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone also struggling with this, it turns out when you nest click handlers, each one starts running on a separate thread or something. Notice below:

http://jsfiddle.net/054nkc2a/

If you click the First button, the Second button's click handler gets activated. Upon clicking the Second button, the function inside its click handler runs ONCE.

However, if you click the First button twice and then click the Second button; the function inside the Second button's click handler runs TWICE!

One possible solution to stop this from happening is to have the second button 'unbind' after it has done what it was supposed to. So if you click the First button, then the Second button and then click Unbind, the Second button should now have no click handler (like it was initially when the page loaded). Then the process repeats.

I hope this helps someone out because this happened to be the solution for my problem :)

HTML:

```
<button id="button1">First</button>
<button id="button2">Second</button>
<button id="unbind">Unbind</button>

<div class="text"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $text = $('.text');

    $('#button1').click(function() {
        $text.append('<p>First</p>')

        $('#button2').click(function() {
            $text.append('<p>Second</p>')
        });

        $('#unbind').click(function() {
            $('#button2').unbind('click');
        });
    });

});
```